# 1 сеть (статическая организация), 2 маршрутизатора и на каждом свой провайдер

Tags: windows, сеть, tp-link

Помогите пожалуйста начинающему системному :)

Имею в наличии локальную сеть вида 192.168.1.Х, где отключен DHCP, все прописано статически. Появилась необходимость добавить в эту сеть роутер с другим провайдером так, чтобы в случае отключения одного клиенты переходили на другой шлюз и dns и обратно.

Спасибо всем неравнодушным :)

Comment: Ставьте dual-WAN роутер.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не относится к тематике сайта.